Encore.ts doesn't allow to choose from other templates than Uptime monitor
I am trying to create an empty app with encore.ts but when I run the command encore app create itonly gives me the Uptime Monitor template option to choose.
I am on the latest encore version - v1.42.1. Please let me know if anyone knows anything about this. I am using TypeScript

Edit: Someone with more reputation please create the encore.ts & encore.go tags

Update: Encore, now allows selecting from templates. I updated to a recently released version and it was fixed
